# Location not correctly displaying when trying to set map from lat and long co-ordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have an intent that chooses a location from google maps and sends the double longitude and latitude values to another intent. In that activity, I have a Map Fragment which is supposed to show the location on a map according to the latitude and longitude values I get. I am correctly getting the doubles values to the activity, but it does not show the correct location. I tried debugging all day, but since there is no error, I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. Here is my class

```
public class Loc extends FragmentActivity{

double latitude;
double longitude;
TextView lat;
TextView lng;
EditText one;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.showmap);
    lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    lng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    one = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);



    // Receiving latitude from MainActivity screen
    double latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lat", 0);

    // Receiving longitude from MainActivity screen
    double longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lng", 0);
    String lats = String.valueOf(latitude);
    String lngs = String.valueOf(longitude);
    lat.setText(lats);
    lng.setText(lngs);

    LatLng position = new LatLng(longitude, latitude);

    // Instantiating MarkerOptions class
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting position for the MarkerOptions
    options.position(position);

    // Setting title for the MarkerOptions
    options.title("Position");

    // Setting snippet for the MarkerOptions
    options.snippet("Latitude:"+latitude+",Longitude:"+longitude);

    // Getting Reference to SupportMapFragment of activity_map.xml
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting reference to google map
    GoogleMap googleMap = fm.getMap();

    // Adding Marker on the Google Map
    googleMap.addMarker(options);

    // Creating CameraUpdate object for position
    CameraUpdate updatePosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);

    // Creating CameraUpdate object for zoom
    CameraUpdate updateZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(4);

    // Updating the camera position to the user input latitude and longitude
    googleMap.moveCamera(updatePosition);

    // Applying zoom to the marker position
    googleMap.animateCamera(updateZoom);
}


}
```

This is where I'm calling this class

```
public class Map extends Activity {


Button ok;
WebView webview;
String q;
TextView add;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    TextView url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvURL);
    add = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
    Button done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //webview.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355");
    webview.loadUrl("https://goo.gl/maps/Fz0KJ");



    //String url1 = uri.toString();


    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
            String q1="";
            String str = webview.getUrl();
            //Uri uri = Uri.parse(str);
            //uri.getQueryParameter(q1);
            ///Log.d("lats",q1);
            String[] part1 = str.split(Pattern.quote("@"));
            String[] part2 = part1[1].split(Pattern.quote(","));

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(part2[0]);
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(part2[1]);
            add.setText(lat+","+lon);


            final Intent yourIntent = new Intent(Map.this, Loc.class);
            yourIntent.putExtra("lat", lat);
            yourIntent.putExtra("lng", lon);
            //setResult(101, yourIntent); 
            startActivity(yourIntent);
            //finish();
            }catch(NullPointerException ex){
                System.out.println (ex.toString());
                Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Slow internet. Please wait till the map loads", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: How much different is the location? Target and received lat, lng coordinates would be nice.

Comment: It shows the sea close to Greenland. My lat longs are 1.532528,110.358054. Supposed to be Swinburne University, Sarawak, Malaysia

Comment: Could you do `Marker marker =googleMap.addMarker(options);` and then print `marker.get position()`?

Comment: @antonio, I did what you said. I'm getting 90.0 as long value instead of 110.358054

Comment: Then I think that @agamov is right and at some point you are changing the latitude and the longitude. The maximum latitude value is 90 and as 110 is greater it's interpreted as 90

Comment: @antonio I changed the two values. Now I'm getting the values correctly, but the map still shows the same place. Some sea near Greenland :(

Comment: Could you post your new code? If you could post also the code where you are calling your `Loc` activity it would be great

Comment: @antonio, I have updated the code and added the other class as well

Comment: @antonio, apparently, the marker is dropped in the correct place, but it zooms into a wrong position. Any idea how to rectify this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That's odd, if the marker is placed in the correct location, it won't move when you zoom in. If you get the marker's position with `getPosition()` and it is correct, it can only be changed with `setPosition()` or dragging it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78681/discussion-between-yohan-blake-and-antonio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and private conversation on chat, the solution is to create a `CameraPosition` using a `CameraPosition.Builder` and then calling `animateCamera()` using the `CameraPosition`:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder() 
    .target(position) 
    .zoom(4) // Set your preferred zoom level here
    .build(); 
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

You can also set the tilt and bearing. Take a look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views?hl=fr-FR#updating_the_camera_view)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your coordinates vice versa.
This could be your case. At least I always fall into this situation :)

Comment: Good thinking. But nope, still the same

Comment: apparently, the marker is dropped in the correct place, but it zooms into a wrong position. Any idea how to rectify this?